# jQuery - Finding radio button by its value

Tags: jquery

I'm scratching my head over this one.

HTML:

```
<form>
      <input name="changes" type="radio" value="2012-05-18T16%3A53%3A00.000000000000%2B0100">
      <span>2012-05-18 16:53:00 +0100</span>
      <input name="changes" type="radio" value="2012-05-29T16%3A51%3A00.000000000000%2B0100">
      <span>2012-05-29 16:51:00 +0100</span>
      <input name="changes" type="radio" value="2012-05-31T17%3A30%3A00.000000000000%2B0100">
      <span>2012-05-31 17:30:00 +0100</span>
      <input name="changes" type="radio" value="2012-06-01T16%3A30%3A00.000000000000%2B0100">
      <input id="view-change" type="button" value="View">
</form>
```

In the Chrome JavaScript console:

```
var today = "2012-05-18T16%3A53%3A00.000000000000%2B0100"
$('input[value="2012-05-18T16%3A53%3A00.000000000000%2B0100"]') -> Finds object
$('input[value=today]') -> Nothing
```

Huh? Why can't i select the input using a `var`?

PS. Ive confirmed, `jQuery.type(today)` = `string`

Comment: Wow - i really am rusty on my jQuery! Rookie error. The winner is khomyakoshka for posting the first answer that actually worked (note the extra inverted commas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('input[value="'+today+'"]')
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AZkKT/)

Answer (score 2):

You should do that like this:

```
$('input[value="' + today + '"]');
```

In php you can just insert vars into a string and they will be substituted with their values, but not in javascript. You need to concatenate the string part with the contents of the variable to make it work. Now you are just looking for an input with a value of (literally) 'today', not the contents of the var 'today'.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
$('input[value=' + today + ']')
```

Be careful the string in today doesn't have quotes or brackets. If it does you'll have to escape them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var today = "2012-05-18T16%3A53%3A00.000000000000%2B0100"
$('input[value="2012-05-18T16%3A53%3A00.000000000000%2B0100"]')
$('input[value=today]')
```

Here, you are giving 'today' as string to use that as variable, you should give like

```
$('input[value='+today+']')
```

It should work!